# Allocating an array in a struct in a separate function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I am initializing an instance of a struct called "UI_Element" across two functions. I first allocate memory to UI_Element* e, and then pass the address of a float array inside of e to a function where memory is allocated to the float array:

```
typedef struct UI_Element {
    float* verts;
    float* UVs;
    int verts_size;
    int UVs_size;
    int tri_count;
    float screen_pos_x;
    float screen_pos_y;
    float font_size;
    char* text;
    size_t text_length;
} UI_Element;

void font_gen_UVs(char* input, int size, float** output)
{
    static int i;
    static int twi;
    *output = malloc(size*12*sizeof(float));
    static float x;
    static float y;
    const float od16 = 1.0f/16.0f;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        twi = i*12;
        x = (input[i] % 16) / 16.0;
        y = (input[i] / 16) / 16.0;

        *output[twi] = x + od16;
        *output[twi+1] = y;
        *output[twi+2] = x;
        *output[twi+3] = y;
        *output[twi+4] = x;
        *output[twi+5] = y + od16;

        *output[twi+6] = x;
        *output[twi+7] = y + od16;
        *output[twi+8] = x + od16;
        *output[twi+9] = y + od16;
        *output[twi+10] = x + od16;
        *output[twi+11] = y;
    }
}

UI_Element* element_init(float screen_pos_x, float screen_pos_y, float font_size, char* text)
{
    int text_length = strlen(text)+1;
    UI_Element* e = malloc(sizeof(UI_Element));
    font_gen_UVs(text, text_length, &e->UVs);
    
   
    return e;
}
```

This does not work properly. e->UVs contains garbage after element_init() is run.
What *does* work: making a new float array inside font_gen_UVs and returning it in this fashion:

```
float* font_gen_UVs(char* input, int size)
{
    static int i;
    static int twi;
    float* output = malloc(size*12*sizeof(float));
    static float x;
    static float y;
    const float od16 = 1.0f/16.0f;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        twi = i*12;
        x = (input[i] % 16) / 16.0;
        y = (input[i] / 16) / 16.0;

        output[twi] = x + od16;
        output[twi+1] = y;
        output[twi+2] = x;
        output[twi+3] = y;
        output[twi+4] = x;
        output[twi+5] = y + od16;

        output[twi+6] = x;
        output[twi+7] = y + od16;
        output[twi+8] = x + od16;
        output[twi+9] = y + od16;
        output[twi+10] = x + od16;
        output[twi+11] = y;
    }
    return output;
}

UI_Element* element_init(float screen_pos_x, float screen_pos_y, float font_size, char* text)
{
    int text_length = strlen(text)+1;
    UI_Element* e = malloc(sizeof(UI_Element));
    e->UVs = font_gen_UVs(text, text_length);
    
   
    return e;
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: I don't remember the C precedence order off the top of my head, but check that `*output[twi]` is being parsed as `(*output)[twi]` (correct) and not `*(output[twi])` (incorrect)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That was it! Thank you